# String corruption when calling menu_layer

Tags: c, string, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm having a very hard time tracing down a strange error in my pebble watch app. I suspect it's a memory error but I can't find my mistake. I have an array of strings, and when I call `menu_layer = menu_layer_create(bounds);` it somehow seems to be corrupting my string. I explain more fully below. The description of the error is bolded.

I have a header files which declares three variables as extern so that they're global.

```
//externs.h
#ifndef EXTERNS_H
#define EXTERNS_H

// These global variables are accessible by all source files. Modified in main.c
extern int str_count;
extern char **str_titles;
extern char **str_teasers;

#endif
```

These three variables are modified in main.c, but are used in other c files. Below is a sample of my main.c file where I set the array of strings `str_titles` and `str_teasers`. The structure `info` contains two strings which are very long but are separated with the delimiter `|`. I copy these strings into a temporary buffer `s_buffer` and parse them apart with `strtok`, saving each new string into my array of strings.

This seems to work well, I've checked each string in a for loop and the last character is always the null-terminated byte and the one previous to it is a period (end of the sentence). I don't modify these values anywhere else, and I don't free them until the very very end of my program (because they should exist for the program's life).

I create a menu with a dynamic number of entries (in this case 6), and each menu has the title of one of the 6 strings within `str_titles`. There are no issues here. I can iterate through and `APP_LOG` this array of strings with no problem at any time in my program.

**When each menu item is pressed, it should display the longer string from `str_teasers` in a scroll layer. It does this reliably only for the first three menu items. For the last three it is always blank. Trying to iterate and print the array of strings here with `APP_LOG` produces a litany of errors in the python framework used with the pebble logs and always ends with something like:**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**The last part `invalid start byte` is sometimes something different, and the decode bytes and position changes based on the string. Note that in the logs always produces some error for the last three blank menu items, and only sometimes does it produce the error for the first three even if the scroll layer is not blank and displays the correct text (for the first three sometimes it prints to the logs without issue).**

**I've tried `APP_LOG` on `str_teasers` at various points, and when it fails, it does so after I call `menu_layer = menu_layer_create(bounds);` to create my menu. Before I make that call I can print all the strings with APP_LOG with no issue at all. I thought it was a heap corruption error, but I have available heap memory (~8100 Bytes) before and after the creation of the layer and my app doesn't crash.**

Maybe I'm missing something very simple, but I can't find my mistake. I've allocated the memory for `str_teasers` correctly I believe, so I don't see why it should be modified at all. I've included a modified sample code below for reference.

```
//main.c
#include "strtok.h"
#include "externs.h"

int str_count;
char **str_titles;
char **str_teasers;

char *s_buffer;
const char delim[1] = "|";
char *token;

typedef struct {
  int s_count;
  char* s_titles;
  char* s_teasers;
} s_info;
s_info info;


// Sample code

str_count = info.s_count;

// Declare arrays of appropriate size
str_titles = malloc(str_count * sizeof(char*));
str_teasers = malloc(str_count * sizeof(char*));

// This creates a copy of the entire string s_titles into s_buffer
int len = strlen(info.s_titles) + 1;
s_buffer = (char *)malloc(len);
strcpy(s_buffer, info.s_titles);

token = strtok(s_buffer, delim); // Get the first token for the titles

// Walk through the other tokens
int counter = 0;
while(token != NULL) {
  *(str_titles + counter) = malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  *(str_titles + counter) = token;
  token = strtok(NULL, delim);
  counter++;
}

// This creates a copy of the entire string s_teasers into s_buffer
len = strlen(info.s_teasers) + 1;
s_buffer = (char *)realloc(s_buffer, len);
strcpy(s_buffer, info.s_teasers);

token = strtok(s_buffer, delim); // Get the first token for the teasers

// Walk through the other tokens
counter = 0;
while(token != NULL) {
  *(str_teasers + counter) = malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  *(str_teasers + counter) = token;
  token = strtok(NULL, delim);
  counter++;
}
free(s_buffer);
```

Comment: You don't appear to have a `main` function. Executable statements have to be within a function. Have you included `stdlib.h` for `malloc` and `string.h` for `strcpy`? Have you supplied your own `strtok`? If so, it is inadvisable to duplicate a library function name. Please see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is just a sample from my `main.c` file, it does have the requisite `main` function. The actual function is much larger so this is just the relevant parts. And yes I had to supply my own `strtok` because pebble does not support the official library name, I got it from [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/string.subproj/strtok.c). I've checked though and it does seem to be returning the correct strings terminated with a null character (at any rate `strlen` would return null I believe if it wasn't).

Comment: You need to add executable code that has the issue. A blob of code we cannot execute difficult to help. Also, if you dump tons of code in here then it looks like you've not tried to narrow the problem down yourself.

Comment: @Harry. The issue would only be reproducible if you have a pebble watch and I supplied you with all of my source code. That's why I supplied the relevant commented sections and explanation of my error hoping someone would see something obvious that I might be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code block

```
// Walk through the other tokens
int counter = 0;
while(token != NULL) {
  *(str_titles + counter) = malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  *(str_titles + counter) = token;
  token = strtok(NULL, delim);
  counter++;
}
```

you allocate memory but immediately overwrite the pointer with the token pointer. Then, in the other, similar code block, you have overwritten the string into which these point. You might have been "lucky" since the memory was reallocated, and the previous string memory was still untouched by other processes. And indeed, you end by freeing this string buffer anyway, without having copied the tokens.

I think you need a `strcpy` here

```
// Walk through the other tokens
int counter = 0;
while(token != NULL) {
  *(str_titles + counter) = malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(*(str_titles + counter), token);         // <<--- here
  token = strtok(NULL, delim);
  counter++;
}
```

Similarly for the teasers code block.

I also notice that you index by `counter` but have not checked it against the `str_count` you were supplied with, which was used to allocate memory for the array of string pointers.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I made your correction and it works as expected. I was getting lucky before which is what I suspected was happening, but wasn't sure why. I'm still a little rusty with C so sometimes I miss really obvious errors like this. Also I'm not checking `str_count` against counter because I'm 100% sure that there will be the same number of strings within my array as the value of str_count. These are variables that come from a companion .js app where the number of strings is dependent explicitly on the value of `str_count`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the vote! Re the range checking: *NEVER* trust an external source of data. Be robust. It might be a pain to implement but if you make this your working style it will pay off big time.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion, thanks. I'll be sure to implement this check to improve the robustness.